# Do I need two separate installations of Magento for multi site?

Tags: magento

I have been trying to setup multi site multi domain setup in Magento for more than a week now. And no success! I first tried to do it on localhost then I tried to do it on live server (shared hosting).

I followed this tutorial http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-multi-site-multi-domain-setup but nothing happens.

Can someone answer to my basic question? Do I need two separate Magento installations to perform multi site multi domain setup or only one installation with two domains? I am confused. Please, help!

Regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run more than one Magento store on a single installation.  The clue is in the `index.php`, specifically:

```
/* Store or website code */
$mageRunCode = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] : 'default';

/* Run store or run website */
$mageRunType = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE'] : 'store';

Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType);
```

The `$mageRunCode` defines the code of the store, or website, (as defined in the `Manage Store` section of the Administration area) that we're initialising.  The `$mageRunType` defines whether we're going to be initialising a store, or a website.

As you can see, Magento first checks for appropriate values as environment variables.  Using apache as an example, values for these variables will need to be set in the `VirtualHost` section of your `httpd.conf`, or similar.  We set the environment variables using the `SetEnv` directive:

```
SetEnv MAGE_RUN_TYPE website
SetEnv MAGE_RUN_CODE website_code_001
```

We can use the same `DocumentRoot` for all of our domains as we're allowing the `VirtualHost` to switch the values of `$_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_{CODE,TYPE}']` depending on the requested hostname.